# Sending Email using java program

Tags: java, email, smtp, gmail

I am using the following program for sending email through Java. When I use this program, I am not getting any error. At that same time I am not getting out it, means the mail is being not sent. I am trying to send message to Gmail. Are these smtp correct or not?

`props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");`

`props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");`

```
package mail;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class mail4 {

    private String from;
    private String to;
    private String subject;
    private String text;

    public mail4(String from, String to, String subject, String text){

        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void send(){

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        Message simpleMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

        InternetAddress fromAddress = null;
        InternetAddress toAddress = null;
        try {

            fromAddress = new InternetAddress(from);
            toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            simpleMessage.setFrom(fromAddress);
            simpleMessage.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
            simpleMessage.setSubject(subject);
            simpleMessage.setText(text);
                        Transport.send(simpleMessage);


        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}




main class
***********

package mail;
public class mail5 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String from = "xxx@gmail.com";
        String to = "yyy@gmail.com";
        String subject = "Test";
        String message = "A test message";
        mail4 sendMail = new mail4(from, to, subject, message);
        sendMail.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: ya both are correct but what error you are getting
?

Comment: Am not getting any error.At that same time the mail was not reached "TO" address.when i type one print statement before  Transport.send(simpleMessage);it will print .I try to print that same statement after Transport.send(simpleMessage); it will not printed.

Comment: write catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
        } and see the printstacktrace i hade come across such exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the port is `587` unless you're using TLS (for which `465`) is correct.
You're not providing any authentication data:
Try this:

```
Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, 
  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
      return new PasswordAuthentication("xxxxxx", "xxxxxx");
    }
  }
 );
```

Comment: I use the 587.but I have the AuthenticationFailedException.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following property:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
```

If this doesn't work, check the following links:

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t141237-send-smtp-mail-using-javamail-with-gmail-account.html

http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip115.html

Comment: When I use this line I have an following error    javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:267)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:137)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:86)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:150)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
        at mail.mail4.send(mail4.java:60)
        at mail.mail5.main(mail5.java:15)

Comment: @fernandas In the first link I have sent you, check out the last answer it has a complete code with authentication

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I misread the code. You need to use port 587 since it's the GMail's SMTP port. Also you can edit yoru props as follows:

```
String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
int port = 587;
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

Comment: I got this error                                                      javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:267)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:137)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:86)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:150)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
        at mail.mail4.send(mail4.java:65)
        at mail.mail5.main(mail5.java:15)

Comment: Try once more with username and password given to the Transport object    
    `String username = "username";`
    `String password = "password";`
    ...
    `Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");`
    `transport.connect(host, port, username, password);`
    `Transport.send(message);`